# is there a way to delete a taxonomy term without deleting its children in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Is there a way to delete a taxonomy term without its children being deleted and without going through the Taxonomy Manager contributed module (This module causes a problem when editing a term)?

Thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try instead to first move the Children Terms out from under the Parent term? Then delete the Parent Term?

1. In the Admin go to the Taxonomy Dashboard: /admin/structure/taxonomy
2. Locate the Taxonomy, click List Terms.
3. Edit the Child Term, go to Relations, adjust the Parent Terms to .
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS4Ue.png) Click Save.
4. Repeat for each Child Term. Then delete the Parent Term.